# JavaScript Custom JSON Names Childs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, parent-child

I am trying to create a JSON Array:

```
let someJSON = {};
someJSON["number1"] = "someString";
```

works. But when I want to set a "Child" to number1 it fails:

```
someJSON["number1"]["date"] = "19.01.2017";
```

I tried some things but its not working :(
I need to create the JSON like this because I needs variables as parents

Comment: There is no JSON in the question. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: You're also not creating an array (which would use `[]`). You're creating an object (`{}`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to create a JSON Array:
>
> ```
> let someJSON = {};
> someJSON["number1"] = "someString";
> ```

That's not a JSON array, that's a JavaScript object.

> But when I want to set a "Child" to number1 it fails:
>
> ```
> someJSON["number1"]["date"] = "19.01.2017";
> ```

That's because you're setting a property on a string primative. That will temporarily promote the string primative to an object, set the property, and then throw away the object, effectively doing nothing.

To make `someJSON.number` an object, create an object just like you did for `someJSON` and add properties to it. Or you can do it all at once:

```
let obj = {
    number1: {
        date: "19.01.2017"
    }
};
```

If you want `"someString"` in there somewhere, just put it on another property:

```
let obj = {
    number1: {
        str:  "someString",
        date: "19.01.2017"
    }
};
```

Comment: Might be worth noting that if they want to have a string value (`"someString"`), they can add another property to hold that. E.g., `obj = { number1: {

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the "number1" object first. Note that you won't be able to set a string value for "number1" as it is now an object.

```
let someJSON = {};
someJSON["number1"] = {};
someJSON["number1"]["date"] = "19.01.2017";
```